# How to use a counter inside \titleformat in LaTeX?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am writing a text in LaTeX and I want my `\paragraphs` to be numerated. I am using package `titlesec` and the following sentences:

```
\newcounter{artNumber}
\setcounter{artNumber}{1}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
    {\normalfont}
    {}{1em}{\textbf{Article\value{artNumber}} }
```

So that when I type something like this:

```
\paragraph{A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away...}
```

I want it to become this:

```
Article 1 A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away...
```

I see the word **Article** showing in the PDF, but the number is missing. How can I get it working?

Comment: Tangentially, you might also be looking for what is referred to as _theorems_ in LaTeX: bodys with a numbered heading.

Comment: @MPi Thanks, I didn't know there was a specific site for LaTeX.

UlrichSchwarz: I didn't know than term, I'll read about them. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a new counter, since LaTeX provides a `paragraph` counter for `\paragraph`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
    {\normalfont}
    {}{1em}{\refstepcounter{paragraph}\textbf{Article~\arabic{paragraph}}~}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away\ldots}
\paragraph{A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away\ldots}
\end{document}
```

`\arabic{paragraph}` prints the paragraph counter in Arabic style, while it's stepped before every setting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem. I was not using the counter properly.